# What does the phrase “as_____is to ______” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, reading-aloud, analogy

For example:

> A is a basic thing for B *as C is to D.*

Is it correct?

Please explain with examples if possible.

Comment: This phrasing is how SAT analogy problems were meant to be read.  http://www.mhhe.com/socscience/english/spears/stu3/studisk/verbal_analogies/va_intro.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that sentence, it simply means that A is a basic thing for B **in the same way that C is a basic thing for D.**

The construction in this meaning can sometimes also be joined by *just* for more emphasis:

> A is a basic thing for B **just** as C is to D.

Comment: using just compulsory?

Comment: @VikasKumar No, definitely not compulsory. I meant to just show you that it can be added for emphasis.

Comment: I think using *just* there implies a greater degree of similarity between how A relates to B and how C relates to D. A less "emphatic" alternative might be *A is a basic thing for B **in the same way as** C is [a basic thing to/for] D*.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Should I used gerund with "comfortable" in this sentence: I'm not comfortable using complex words and sentences. ? (I want to use "use" verb only).

Comment: @VikasKumar If you have new questions that are not related to this one, please look for answers on the website and post them as a new question if you cannot find the answer.